# Google spreadsheet pivot table and join

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My concern is about transforming an array to another one :

I have a table like this :

Name Val 1  Val 2
Joe    A    B 
Karl       C 
Joe    C    B

I would like this table as result:

Name A B C
Joe  X X X
Karl      X

I'm lost, I tried using query or ArrayFormula but I failed, if someone can solves this ..?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(""&QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(B2:C="",,A2:A&"×"&B2:C)), "×")), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  pivot Col2 
  label Col1'Name'"), "\d+", "X"))
```

[image]